# How to perform subtraction to find difference between two means in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have two sets of data and I got the means using the custom tables on SPSS, but I couldn’t know how to do some mathematical functions on the means or s.d. Like ratio or difference! Can anyone help please.

Thanks

Comment: If you use `aggregate` command you can get means and SD in a dataset instead of the output window. You can also use `match files` of `add files` to combine datasets (before or after `aggregate`), so you can calculate comparisons between the aggregate values.

Comment: Thanks Eli, but what i meant here is to do the difference on custom table since it already calculates the mean for that data, I just want to do the difference ( subtraction) is there a way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no need to post any code. It is on the custom table how to perform subtraction on means in order to find the difference.